# You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies:

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgles-dev : Depends: libegl-dev but it is not installed
               Depends: libgl-dev
 libglvnd-dev : Depends: libegl-dev (>= 1.3.0-1) but it is not installed
                Depends: libgl-dev (>= 1.3.0-1)
                Depends: libglx-dev (>= 1.3.0-1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Unfortunately your question is impossible to answer, as you're not asking any. Please check [How to write a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help). In general I'd advise to take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and go through the Asking- and Answering -sections of Help to get a handle on how these communities work. In this case you have clear advice from the system what to do - what are the results when you run 'apt --fix-broken install'?

Comment: Forgot - please [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/734670/edit) your question instead of answering or adding new information in the comments. That way all the relevant info is directly available for the community members. Also when you find a solution for your issue, don't hesitate to [write an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and [Accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it. This makes it helpful others looking for solution to similar issue.

Comment: I am in the same  situation with Debian 11. Some install triggered updating the kernel and by accident, I had testing iin the sources.list. If you find a nice solution, pls let me know